# Why does initialising a static const member variable array in the .cpp result in a incomplete type error when used in another file?

Tags: c++

Why does this result in a compile error?

SourceToken.h:

```
struct SourceToken {
  // Regex Specifications
  static const std::pair<std::string, std::regex> kSpecs[];

  const std::string type;
  const std::string value;
};
```

SourceToken.cpp:

```
const std::pair<std::string, std::regex> SourceToken::kSpecs[] = {
    {SourceToken::kWhitespace std::regex("^\\s+")},
};
```

In another .cpp file:

```
// Inside a function.
for (const auto &spec : SourceToken::kSpecs) {
    // Do something...
}
```

I get the error:

```
error: range-based ‘for’ expression of type ‘const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_regex<char> > []’ has incomplete type
   13 |   for (const auto &spec : SourceToken::kSpecs) {
```

If I were to change the plain array into a `std::vector`, or to define the array inside the header, it will compile without issues.

Comment: Size is unknown with just header...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a static member variable in one file (SourceToken.cpp), it's only visible within that source file by default. Other .cpp files are not aware of its definition, so you get the `Incomplete Type Error`.

When you use a static array, the size of the array needs to be known at compile time. Other source files can only see the declaration of your static array but not the definition (unless you put the definition in the header).

Using `std::vector` instead works because it's a dynamic container, and its size can be determined at runtime.

Comment: So if I want to put it in the .cpp file, there's just no way for me to use a plain array? I was thinking of using an std::array, but even then I would need to declare the size in the header.

Comment: if you don't know the size at compile time, array is not usable.

Comment: @TypeDefinition: `static const std::pair<std::string, std::regex> kSpecs[1];` would be OK.